# PHP Form to SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write from form to my SQL database. This is all local through WAMP, if that makes a difference.

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
Error: INSERT INTO customers (yard, full_address, business_name, business_status, first_name, last_name, landline_number, mobile_number, email_address) VALUES ('Dominic', '123 Fake Street', 'Dom's Business Name', '', 'Dominic', 'Fichera', 0123456789', '0123456789', '')
Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de 's Business Name', '', 'Dominic', 'Fichera', 0123456789', '0123456789', '')' � la ligne 2
```

I've also uploaded an image here: http://s7.postimg.org/ecqci36nv/error_snippet.png

I am unsure if this error refers to an issue within my code, an issue with the way I've setup my SQL table or something completely different.

Here is the main chunk of my code where all of the action happens:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["yard"])) {
     $yard_error = "Yard is required";
   } else {
     $yard = test_input($_POST["yard"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["full_address"])) {
     $full_address_error = "Address is required";
   } else {
     $full_address = test_input($_POST["full_address"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
     $first_name_error = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["last_name"])) {
     $last_name_error = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
   }

   if ($_POST["business_status"] = "") {
     $business_status_error = "Business status is required";
   } else {
     $business_status = test_input($_POST["business_status"]);
   }

   $business_name = $_POST["business_name"];
    $landline_number = $_POST["landline_number"];
    $mobile_number = $_POST["mobile_number"];
    $email_address = $_POST["email_address"];

   // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (yard, full_address, business_name,         business_status, first_name, last_name, landline_number, mobile_number,     email_address)
VALUES ('$yard', '$full_address', '$business_name', '$business_status',     '$first_name', '$last_name', $landline_number', '$mobile_number',     '$business_status')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $yard_confirmation = $yard . "successfully saved.";
} else {
    $yard_confirmation = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

    }

    function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: You need to escape your user input. That is why you got an error

Comment: `'Dom's Business Name'` see this? Read about data escaping.

Comment: it's clearly an issue with an apostrophe at "Dom's Business", escape that string

Comment: You're not running `$business_name` through `test_input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend something like this:

```
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```

And:

```
$errors = array();
($_POST["business_name"]) ? $business_name = test_input($_POST["business_name"]) : $errors[] = "Business name is required!";
```

(Doing the same line for each $_POST variable)

Basically it's an if/else statement in one line (reduces clutter). If there is data in $_POST["business_name"], then $business_name will have the value parsed through test_input - if it has no value, then the errors array gets a new value!

After checking all the values and parsing them, you can do:

```
if(empty($errors)) {
    //If there are no errors, continue inserting
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (yard, full_address, business_name, business_status, first_name, last_name, landline_number, mobile_number, email_address) VALUES ('$yard', '$full_address', '$business_name', '$business_status', '$first_name', '$last_name', $landline_number', '$mobile_number', '$business_status')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $yard_confirmation = $yard . "successfully saved.";
    } else {
        $yard_confirmation = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
} else {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error."<br />";
    }
}
```

I would definitely recommend using PDO though, it allows you to bind values to queries.

Answer (score 0):

`'Dom's Business Name'` is invalid, you'll need to escape it:

```
'Dom\'s Business Name'
```

Please consider using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You SQL-injected your own database lol. Though you do have a function for adding slashes called `test_input()` you forgot to use it in some places. Change these:

```
$business_name = $_POST["business_name"];
$landline_number = $_POST["landline_number"];
$mobile_number = $_POST["mobile_number"];
$email_address = $_POST["email_address"];
```

To these:

```
$business_name = test_input($_POST["business_name"]);
$landline_number = test_input($_POST["landline_number"]);
$mobile_number = test_input($_POST["mobile_number"]);
$email_address = test_input($_POST["email_address"]);
```

I'd encourage reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

In your query, your listed values, you're missing a single quote before `"$landline_number"`.

Also, since you're not using prepared statements, I HIGHLY recommend you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for all user submitted variables to prevent injection. For example:

```
$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['variable']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this php function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and prepare your string before saving into database.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, the problem is with apostrophe in the business name, but it could be with other characters that need to be escaped. And worst, your code is a candidate to be a victim of SQL injection.

For a solution, line:

```
$business_name = $_POST["business_name"];
```

should be changed by :

```
if ($_POST["business_name"] = "") {
 $business_name_error = "Business name is required";
} else {
 $business_name = test_input($_POST["business_name"]);
}
```

And the following three lines should be change in the same way.